# UINavigationController — left and right flip animation between pushes and pops when presented via presentViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimation

Supposed you've got:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    rootViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [self.window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    UINavigationController *modal = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[PTFrontViewController alloc] init]];
    modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    [rootViewController presentViewController:modal animated:YES completion:NULL];

    return YES;
}
```

whereas `PTFrontViewController` and `PTBackViewController` view controllers have nothing interesting for sake of this example.

How could you push an instance of `PTBackViewController` from `PTFrontViewController` animating as in `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft` or `UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight`?

I am already well aware of these three things:

1. this is not exactly how you should make use of `presentViewController`
2. there is a good reason for `UINavigationController`'s default animation
3. there are several answers how to "customize" `UINavigationController`'s default animation while pushing and poping, but if you try the code for your self you will notice that when a view controller is presented via `presentViewController` there are drop shadows and background views that won't get animated correctly

So please answer taking these things in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - forget `UINavigationController`. If you don't need the default animation, just put a `UINavigationBar` into your controllers. It will get a little easier.

Second - this is a difficult problem, you can't create such an animation only within the modal controller because the background wouldn't be repainted.

Sincerely, the easist solution I see is too forget the modal controller and just add the view controller as a child of your root controller. Then you can control all the animations but you have to write everything by yourself (including the background fading).